# How to Upload the file in frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9

I created the custom option for file upload, If i choose the file and click the upload button i want to upload file, i don't know how to do this
[image: customoption]

In Magento if choose the file and click the add to cart button file uploaded but I don't want this functionality.so what i need is if I click the upload button after choose the file, i want to upload the file. this is my code.

```
$jq(document).ready(function(){

    $jq("#click-me").click(function(){
             var imgVal = $jq('.choose').val();
            if(imgVal==''){
            return false;
            }
            else{
                $jq( "#myProgress" ).removeClass( "hide-progress" ).addClass( "add-progress" );


            }
        move();

        });

});
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
     }
     }

}
```

can you please help..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code in your controller action to upload the file:

```
 if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))) {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            }
```

Comment: I added some code in my question.please help

Comment: I have provided the code to upload file. To implement progress bar you will find lot of reference from google.

Comment: After I upload the file,I want show that file in cart page and ordered that product,I want to show that file in admin page.I removed the upload file Fuctionality from **file.php** please help

Answer (score 2):

well native magento wont provide by the default that feature.

you can intigrate third party libraries for that just like [plUpload](http://www.plupload.com/)

so use that kind of library.